# What to modify when my SVN server's IP address changes in Xcode?

Tags: svn, xcode

I get the following error in Xcode:

> Error: 175002 (RA layer request failed) Description: OPTIONS of 'http://User@192.168.0.107/svn/MyProj/MyProj.xcodeproj': could not connect to server (http://192.168.0.107)

I made two changes since the last time it worked:

- The local IP address of the computer it's connected to has changed (which obviously would explain why it can't connect)
- I upgraded from SDK 4.0 to 4.1

I tried to fix it by doing the following:

- I went to SCM > Repositories
- Configured my repository and set the new IP address.

It correctly shows the "M" icons near each file that was modified, however, I still get these error messages occasionally, meaning that the old IP address is still stored somewhere.

What else do I need to modify when the IP address changes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you originally checked out the tree using `http://User@192.168.0.107/svn/MyProj` (say), then every folder in your working copy will still have a reference to the old location. You need to use `svn switch --relocate` like so:

```
cd MyProj
svn switch --relocate http://User@192.168.0.107/svn/MyProj http://User@newip/svn/MyProj
```

Don't be puzzled that files show up as M, and that svn can still compute diffs correctly - these are both local operations that require no repository access.

Comment: That worked, thanks. The command `svn info` can also help to see the current URL used by any given directory.